# Prove that there exists a bipartite graph $G(A, B, E)$ such that every vertex in set $A$ has degree $n^{3/4}$ if $|A| = |B|$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, bipartite-graphs

Prove that there exists a bipartite graph with vertex set $V = A \cup B$, where $|A| = |B| = n$, such that all vertices in set $A$ have degree $n^{3/4}$ and all vertices in $B$ have degree at most $3n^{3/4}$.

Also, every subset of $A$ of size $n^{3/4}$ should have at least $n - n^{3/4}$ neighbours in $B$.

I know I can solve this problem using the property p1: sum of the degrees of the vertices in $A$ equals the sum of the degrees of vertices in $B$.

I need to prove that a bipartite graph can be created which will satisfy the above two properties.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you miss a condition here? The edgeless graph (say, with 16 vertices) is a counterexample.

Comment: Could you please explain how come a disconnected graph is a counter-example?

Comment: It contains vertices which do not have degree $n^{3/4}$...?

Comment: then the graph is not bipartite too I guess.

Comment: What is your definition of bipartite graph?

Comment: not sufficient condition but the simple condition would be graph is bipartite if and only if it is 2-colourable.
If a graph is edgeless it's 1 colourable. 
If I mention that number of edges need to be > n and n > 3 will it helps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99707/discussion-between-user730119-and-79037662).